# Reconstruct Original Data using Denoising AutoEncoder

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

Sometimes , the raw data doesn't contains sufficient information like biological experimental data.I have a gene expression dataset with size 100*1000. I want to use Denoising AutoEncoder to get an reconstructed output with the same size(100*1000). How it would be possible?

Comment: Do you expect your denosing autoencoder to delete noise from your data? Or do you ask how is it possible that denoising autoencoder can reconstruct the same data which is given?

Comment: Not just to delete noise from data. Denoising autoencoder can extract some rich cor-relational, geometric   features which may improve performance of classification tasks and inference problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an interesting article about autoencoders. The denosing case is also mentioned - I hope that it will answer your question :

https://medium.com/a-year-of-artificial-intelligence/lenny-2-autoencoders-and-word-embeddings-oh-my-576403b0113a#.2jdcn3ctk

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone ever stumbles over this post and wonders how to code a denoising autoencoder. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate a 100x1000 dataset
x_train = np.random.rand(100, 1000)

# Add noise to the data
noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape)

# Clip the values to [0, 1]
x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)

# Define the input layer
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1000,))

# Define the encoder
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(inputs)

# Define the decoder
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# Define the autoencoder model
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, decoded)

# Compile the model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Train the model
autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

Note:

- You have to replace x_train with your data
- x_train has to be noise free (otherwise the denoising autoencoder won't work, since it has no reference)
- you can add additional layers for your encoder and decoder part
- you should play around with hyperparameters (number of neurons in the individual layers, loss function, (optimizer,) epochs, batch_size) to see what works best for you -> preferably, you run an optimisier to find the best values for them (like grid search and the like)

And here are a couple of links to other sources on autoencoders:

[Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/autoencoder-for-classification/)

[Keras Blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html)